# Как с помощью lxml запарсить данные, которые генерируются js через выбор даты в календаре?

Tags: python, lxml

Есть к примеру [такая страница](http://kinoafisha.ua/cinema/kiev/sputnik-)

В конце строки **Расписание сеансов в Спутник на среду 9 сентября** есть календарь. В этом календаре дни, в которых есть сеансы, выделены черным и имеют тег `<a href="#"></a>`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью lxml "переключать" дни, имеющие этот тег, чтоб js генерировал расписание сеансов по каждому дню, которые затем можно будет парсить?

Думаю построить цикл "проверить день на наличие тега `<a>` --> если есть тег, то "кликнуть день" --> запарсить расписание --> проверить следующий день на наличие тега `<a>`". Как сделать вот этот "клик" с помощью lxml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) -- это библиотека, помогающая распознать xml/html документы. `lxml` не является браузером и не выполняет javascript во время чтения html страниц.

Чтобы [получить html-код, сгенерированный javascript-ом](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960288/4279), на странице, можно использовать selenium webdriver (e.g., `webdriver.PhantomJS`).